# Category of 'marked' vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, category-theory, field-theory

**CONTEXT**

From some time on I've been loosely thinking about conjugation of complex numbers as an autofunctor of the category of $\Bbb C$-vector spaces. Although I don't remember having found it anywhere in the literature, it just seemed an obvious possibility for me, and a particularly useful one when thinking about Hermitian forms, thus sending all the information about antilinearity of certain maps (a notion that seemingly results in two types of morphisms; for instance, how would you *add* a linear map and an antilinear one?) to the 'inside' of some 'extra' objects, keeping every single map plainly 'linear'.

Today, for a simple reason I won't mention, I finally stumped on the need of formalizing such a way of thinking about conjugation. As I had expected, it was not very hard to do so. Though, I'm not sure if the definition I managed to produce will endure all the difficulties Mathematics shall impose to it (haha), so I decide to share it here, expecting either to find some references on the subject, or at least to get some hints on the problems I'll have to overcome. I tried to write it in a slightly more general way.

**DEFINITIONS**

Let $E/F$ be a field extension and let ${\rm Aut}(E/F)$ denote its automorphism group. We shall denote by $Vect_{E/F}$ the category of $E$-vector spaces 'marked' with elements of
${\rm Aut}(E/F)$. More precisely, the objects of $Vect_{E/F}$ are pairs $(V,\alpha)$, where $V$ is an $E$-vector space and $\alpha\in{\rm Aut}(E/F)$, and the morphisms in
$Vect_{E/F}\big((V_1,\alpha_1),(V_2,\alpha_2)\big)$ are functions
$\lambda:\mathcal S(V_1)\to\mathcal S(V_2)$ such that the following diagrams commute:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal S(V_1)\times\mathcal S(V_1)@>(\lambda,\lambda)>>\mathcal S(V_2)\times\mathcal S(V_2)\\
@V\mathcal S(\sigma_1)VV&@VV\mathcal S(\sigma_2)V\\
\mathcal S(V_1)@>>\lambda>\mathcal S(V_2)
\end{CD}\qquad\qquad
\begin{CD}
\mathcal S(E)\times\mathcal S(V_1)@>\theta>>\mathcal S(E)\times\mathcal S(V_2)\\
@V\mathcal S(\mu_1)VV&@VV\mathcal S(\mu_2)V\\
\mathcal S(V_1)@>>\lambda>\mathcal S(V_2)
\end{CD}$$

where $\mathcal S:Vect_E\to Sets$ denotes the forgetful functor,
$\sigma_i:V_i\times V_i\to V_i$ and
$\mu_i:E\times V_i\to V_i$, $i\in\{1,2\}$ denote the usual addition of vectors and scalar multiplication of $E$-vector spaces, and

$$\theta:=(e,v_1)\mapsto\big(\mathcal S(\alpha_2\alpha_1^{-1})(e),\lambda(v_1)\big).$$

Note that this definition keeps the usual definition of $E$-vector spaces, but *changes the definition of morphism* of vector spaces in a way that, at least it seems to me, cannot be promptly obtained from the usual one.

Finally, let $\beta\in{\rm Aut}(E/F)$. Then we can define a functor
$\mathcal F_\beta:Vect_{E/F}\to Vect_{E/F}$ simply by putting

$$\mathcal F_\beta:(V,\alpha)\mapsto(V,\alpha\beta)\qquad\mathcal F_\beta:\lambda\mapsto\lambda.$$

**QUESTIONS**

1. Have you ever found definitions similar to the above ones in the literature? Where?
2. If you didn't, what problems (of any kind) involving these definitions come to your mind?
3. In the case $E/F=\Bbb C/\Bbb R$, denote $V:=(V,1)$ and $\overline V:=(V,-)$. Would you agree that a nondegenerate Hermitian form on $V$ can be described as an isomorphism $\varphi:V\to\overline V^*$ such that $\overline\varphi^*=\varphi$, where $*$ denotes the dual?

Comment: I don't have any answers to your 3 questions, but I'm confused about your first commutative diagram. What are $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$? I don't see them defined anywhere?

Comment: From context, they should be addition of vectors in each of the spaces.

Comment: That's right, I'll fix the question.

Comment: This is basically the category of vector spaces with graded hom spaces of [semilinear maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilinear_map). Like they're slightly different, but also essentially the same in a manner that I can't precisely put my finger on right now.

Answer (score 6):

1. Your definition is a special case of the Grothendieck construction of a (fibered) category out of a contravariant pseudo-functor to the category of categories.
2. N/A
3. No, such an isomorphism would only be a non-degenerate sesqui-linear pairing. You would need symmetry and positive-definite conditions to get a Hermitian form.

Here's some details regarding 1.

For each automorphism $\beta$ of $E$ you have a functor $F_\beta\colon\mathrm{Vect}_E\to\mathrm{Vect}_E$ sending an $E$-vector space $V$ to a new vector space $\beta^*V$ that has the same underlying set and addition of vectors, but scaling given by $(e,v)\mapsto\beta(e)v$; this is functorial because if $V\to W$ ie $E$-linear, then it is also $E$-linear as a function $\beta^*V\to\beta^*W$.

An important feature of these functors is that $F_\beta\circ F_\alpha=F_{\alpha\circ\beta}$ and that $F_{\mathrm{id}}=\mathrm{id}$. In other words, we have a contravariant functor from the automorphism group of $E$ considered as a one-object category to the category of categories, sending the elements of the automorphism group to endofunctors on the category of $E$-vector spaces.

What you are doing is then defining for each automorphism $\beta$ of $E$ a $\beta$-homomorphism of $E$-vector spaces to be an $E$-linear morphism $\lambda\colon V_1\to\beta^*V_2$. The labels here are kind of a red herring: what you call a morphism from $(V_1,\alpha_1)$ to $(V_2,\alpha_2)$ is now an $\alpha_2\circ\alpha_1^{-1}$-morphism from $(\alpha_1^{-1})^*V_1$ to $(\alpha_2^{-1})^*V_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As soon as I can I'll check it in detail. Can you point out a reference for the construction mentioned in answer 1? As for answer 3, isn't the equality $\overline\varphi^*=\varphi$ equivalent to symmetry of the Hermitian form? I'll do the calculation again to check this.